# How to best debug a failed ruby migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My team have recently inherited a legacy ruby codebase which is in a bit of a mess. (I'm not a ruby  dev myself, and the only ruby dev on our team has been in the company >6 months, so we're very much out of our depth)

We've had to add a db column, which has worked as expected in development and staging, however when deploying to prod we encounter an issue starting the db:migrate rake process (migration and message below).

It seems that the deployment for staging uses elastic beanstalk, where as the prod deployment is managed directly by codedeploy into an EC2 instance, so there are definitely some differences (I wish we knew why :/ ).

Any ideas on where to even start looking would be greatly appreciated

```rb
class AddListPriceIncVatAmountToVariants < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :variants, :list_price_inc_vat_amount, :decimal, null: false, default: 0.0

    add_index :variants, :list_price_inc_vat_amount
  end
end
```

```bash
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: comparison of Integer with nil failed
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/logger_thread_safe_level.rb:19:in `>='
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/logger_thread_safe_level.rb:19:in `debug?'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/agent_logger.rb:86:in `format_and_send'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/agent_logger.rb:44:in `debug'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/memory_logger.rb:53:in `block in dump'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/memory_logger.rb:52:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/memory_logger.rb:52:in `dump'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/agent_logger.rb:178:in `gather_startup_logs'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/agent/agent_logger.rb:24:in `initialize'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/control/private_instance_methods.rb:30:in `new'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/control/private_instance_methods.rb:30:in `create_logger'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/new_relic/control/instance_methods.rb:58:in `init_plugin'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.15.0/lib/newrelic_rpm.rb:34:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
/home/ubuntu/platform-api/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:494:in `exec'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config => environment
```

We've tried taking a dump of the production db, and running the migrations locally against that, which all went through without a hitch, so we're quite confident it's not a data issue.

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain.
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  config.action_cable.url = ENV['ACTION_CABLE_URL']
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [%r{https://*.<redacted>.com}]
  config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [:request_id]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
  config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, {
    url: Rails.application.config_for(:redis).cache_url,
    pool_size: ENV.fetch('RAILS_MAX_THREADS', 20),
    pool_timeout: 5
  }
  config.active_record.cache_versioning = false

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment).
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "app_production"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT'].present?
    logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  # Inserts middleware to perform automatic connection switching.
  # The `database_selector` hash is used to pass options to the DatabaseSelector
  # middleware. The `delay` is used to determine how long to wait after a write
  # to send a subsequent read to the primary.
  #
  # The `database_resolver` class is used by the middleware to determine which
  # database is appropriate to use based on the time delay.
  #
  # The `database_resolver_context` class is used by the middleware to set
  # timestamps for the last write to the primary. The resolver uses the context
  # class timestamps to determine how long to wait before reading from the
  # replica.
  #
  # By default Rails will store a last write timestamp in the session. The
  # DatabaseSelector middleware is designed as such you can define your own
  # strategy for connection switching and pass that into the middleware through
  # these configuration options.
  # config.active_record.database_selector = { delay: 2.seconds }
  # config.active_record.database_resolver = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
  # config.active_record.database_resolver_context = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session

  # Loggly
  # require 'syslogger'
  # config.logger = Syslogger.new("platform-api", Syslog::LOG_PID, Syslog::LOG_LOCAL7)

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    user_name: 'apikey', # This is the string literal 'apikey', NOT the ID of your API key
    password: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'], # This is the secret sendgrid API key which was issued during API key creation
    domain: '<redacted>.com',
    address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    port: 587,
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

  config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
                        email: {
                          email_prefix: Rails.env,
                          sender_address: "'Exception Notifier' <#{ENV['SENDGRID_EMAIL']}>",
                          exception_recipients: ['carlo@<redacted>.com']
                        },
                        slack: {
                          webhook_url: ENV['SLACK_WEBHOOK'],
                          channel: '#platform-api',
                          additional_parameters: {
                            mrkdwn: true
                          }
                        }
end
```

Comment: The error points to this line: [`active_support/logger_thread_safe_level.rb:19`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.3.6/activesupport/lib/active_support/logger_thread_safe_level.rb#L19) and along with the error message, it seem like your log level is set to `nil`

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, added config for reference, looks like it's set to :info, is that valid?

Comment: looks like you have new_relic installed, are you missing some configuration for that?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be, I've ran a diff check against the staging config and it's basically identical and works fine :/

Comment: Would you mind sharing the contents of `/home/ubuntu/platform-api/config/environment.rb:5`? It seems like this is the file on your project (outside of the gem files) that is triggering that error.

Comment: ruby versions the same in staging and production? datastores the same? not trying to be insulting. sometimes I miss the simple answers & spin my wheels down in the weeds when the fix is easy. Also, if you rewrite your migration to use SQL directly, does the error still occur? Just random things to check.

Comment: Just a little tip: Database Migrations are a Rails thing and calling it a "Ruby migration" is going to cause raised eyebrows and confusion as it implies that you're changing from one Ruby version to another.

Comment: Ah sorry, as a TS dev it's all the same to me but I can see how that might be confusing.

I think we've found it, for some reason we have the same config for new relic in staging & prod, but it's not actually running in staging at all, so the broken config was never read -_-. 

Thanks for the help!